# Common height of last three images only

Tags: jquery, css, frontend

I have 20+ images on a page and **I am trying to adjust the height of last three images equal** but i cant, can anyone help me how to do this with **jquery** or **css** like (**Last three children condtion**)

[image: Screenshot of problem]

html is:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="thumbs">
</div>
```

css is :

```
img {
width:100%;
height: auto;
}
```

I want to equal the last three images shown above in ref image

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Could you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  function getLastOf(selector, count) {
    var allSpans = $(selector);
    if(count > allSpans.length) {
      return allSpans;
    }
    return allSpans.slice(allSpans.length-count);
  }
  var spans = getLastOf('span',3);
  spans.css('background-color','red');
  var highest = 0;
  spans.each(function(i,e) {
      highest = $(e).height() > highest ? $(e).height() : highest;
  });
  console.log("The highest span is " + highest + "px.");

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span>Text1</span>
    <span>Text2</span>
    <span>Text3</span>
    <span>Text4</span>
```

This should be easily changable for your images.

Comment: But how i know what the height we required for last three images for common height because the height of images are not equal ?

Comment: The way I understood you was that you wanted to calculate the height yourself. I assumed you meant the average to be honest. I don't know what you want. But with those three you can do stuff like `getLastOf('div > img', 3).each(function(index,element) { /* work with what you need */});`.

You could for example take the average or the highest of those three.

Comment: In short i want to make last three image size 100% to height of footer

Comment: Well if you want to do that with jQuery you'd just have to add that in the each function then. You can get your height of the footer and then add `$(element).height(yourFooterheight)`. But if you wanted that to be dynamic a css aproach might be better. Have you considered putting those images in an element with position: relative and a fixed height and then set them to height 100%?